Difficulty Playing YouTube Videos Using VLC in C++
I need to create a function in C++ that plays a YouTube video using VLC.
When I play the video - nothing happens, no window opens, and the video is not played and no errors appearing.
(I'm sure I downloaded VLC and the libraries correctly and connected them correctly to my project because I have a function that I created that plays a local video (a video downloaded to the computer) and it works well).
Thank you very much.
This is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

static void handleVLCEvents(const libvlc_event_t* event, void* userData) {
    switch (event->type) {
    case libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached:
        std::cout << "End of video reached." << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        break; 
    } 
}

int playVideo() {
    libvlc_instance_t* vlcInstance = libvlc_new(0, nullptr);
    libvlc_media_player_t* vlcMediaPlayer = libvlc_media_player_new(vlcInstance);
    libvlc_event_manager_t* vlcEventManager = libvlc_media_player_event_manager(vlcMediaPlayer); 
    libvlc_event_attach(vlcEventManager, libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached, handleVLCEvents, nullptr);

    // Open a YouTube video
    std::string youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZP1rYjoBgI";
    libvlc_media_t* vlcMedia = libvlc_media_new_location(vlcInstance, youtubeURL.c_str());
    libvlc_media_player_set_media(vlcMediaPlayer, vlcMedia);
    libvlc_media_release(vlcMedia);

    // Play the video
    libvlc_media_player_play(vlcMediaPlayer);

    // Keep the program running to display the video
    std::cin.get();

    // Clean up
    libvlc_media_player_stop(vlcMediaPlayer);
    libvlc_media_player_release(vlcMediaPlayer);
    libvlc_release(vlcInstance);

    return 0;
}


I’m fairly sure that libvlc_media_new_location expects a URI pointing to a media resource, not an arbitrary website with an embedded video, which is what you are providing. YouTube doesn’t make it trivial to grab a direct link to the media — that’s why projects like youtube-dl or yt-dlc exist, and have a nontrivial implementation.

Google is always coming up with new schemes to disable direct downloads (and adblockers). Does it work with the VLC application?

You cannot play the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZP1rYjoBgI if you are not authenticated to do so. If you eventually do find a hack, bear in mind that there are legal consequences.

I'm not familiar with libvlc, but I'd be shocked if they don't provide any error codes or messages that would tell you more. You don't check the result of any of the calls to libvlc. You ignore all events except for the one you get after successful playback. Implement error handling/logging, see which call is the first that goes wrong, then investigate starting there. That's step one, asking on stackoverflow comes much later ;)

So you're almost there, but playing a YouTube video (or an m3u playlist) requires just a few more lines of code.
What you're feeding now to LibVLC is the HTML page of the YouTube video, not the direct URL to the video file hosted by YouTube.
So to get that, you need to parse the media and play its subitem (which points to the actual URL, decoded by VLC's lua script). Here are the missing functions in pseudo-code.
libvlc_media_parse_with_options(vlcMedia, libvlc_media_parse_network, -1);
libvlc_media_subitems(vlcMedia);
libvlc_media_player_set_media(vlcMediaPlayer, vlcMediaSubItem);

